# Laravel DB::raw using SELECT column AS "Example Name"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've come across an issue when trying to use a `DB::raw` query with Laravel. When I try to loop through my result set, I can't target a certain column, as it's name contains a space:

```
$result = DB::connection("example")->select(DB::raw(
  "SELECT table.column_1 AS 'NameOne',
  table.column_2 AS 'Name Two'
  FROM example;"
));
```

As you can see, `NameOne` doesn't contain a space, but `Name Two` does. When looping through the result set, I can't echo out the result of `table.column_2 AS 'Name Two`, as I can't target it correctly. What I've tried:

```
<!-- language: html -->
@foreach($result AS $item)
<tr>
  <td>{!! $result->NameOne !!}</td> <!-- Works Fine -->
  <td>{!! $result->Name Two !!}</td> <!-- Doesn't work (obvious syntax error) -->
  <td>{!! $result->Name_Two !!}</td> <!-- Doesn't work (undefined property) -->
  <td>{!! $result->Name+Two !!}</td> <!-- Doesn't work (undefined property) -->
  <td>{!! $result->NameTwo !!}</td> <!-- Doesn't work (undefined property) -->
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Specifically the undefined property error is:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$Name_Two (View: /var/www/html/APPNAME/resources/views/index.blade.php)

I don't want to change the key as these results are being exported to Excel, and I want to preserve column names. Keeping this in mind, how would I echo out these results?

Also, the output for the `dd($results)`:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#179 ▼
    +"NameOne": "NameOne"
    +"Name Two": "NameTwo"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
<td>{!! $result->{'Name Two'} !!}</td>
```

Comment: That does it. Out of curiosity, where did you find this? I checked Laravel's documentation and couldn't find this issue.

Comment: Ah. So it's not a Laravel specific thing then. Good to know!

Comment: Basically, Blade tags are just shorthands for `<?= e(...) ?>` and `<?= ... ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent is returning stdClass. You can easily convert it into array with function ['get_object_vars'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

Then simply call:

```
{!! $result['Name Two'] !!}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. `$result` is an array, not an object (apparently): `get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given`

Comment: Yes, but it will work if you will use this function on single array record. Anyway Damien solution is much better.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't know if I could have implemented that and still had the flexibility I wanted, so I did end up using his solution. Thanks though!